# MongoDB, an Ubuntu user other than root, and storing the PID file in /var/run/mongodb

Tags: linux, mongodb, ubuntu, pid, rc

I am having trouble storing the PID file for mongod in the directory `/var/run/mongodb` and getting the mongod process to start on boot as a user other than `root`.

I have installed MongoDB v2.6.3 on Ubuntu v14.04; created a linux user called `mongodb`; and granted ownership of the directories in the following configuration to that user, using `chown -R mongodb:mongodb {path}`:

```
systemLog:
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log
  logAppend: true
  destination: file

processManagement:
  pidFilePath: /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
  fork: true

security:
  keyFile: /srv/mongodb/keyfile
  clusterAuthMode: keyFile

storage:
  dbPath: /data

replication:
  replSetName: myReplicaSet
```

I understand that only the `root` user can write to the `/var/run` directory, so I added the following code to `/etc/rc.local` in order to create a subdirectory that my `mongodb` user owns:

```
PID_FILE_DIRECTORY=/var/run/mongodb
CONFIG_FILE=/etc/mongod.conf

do_start () {
  if [ ! -d $PID_FILE_DIRECTORY ]; then
    mkdir $PID_FILE_DIRECTORY
    chown -R mongodb:mongodb $PID_FILE_DIRECTORY
  fi
  setuid mongodb
  mongod -f $CONFIG_FILE
}

exit 0
```

When I reboot the server, I expect mongod to start as if the user `mongodb` had run the mongod command. However, when I check the logs I see the error:

```
ERROR: Cannot write pid file to /var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid: No such file or directory
```

I noticed in `/etc/init.d` there was a file called `mongod` that appeared to be overriding my commands in `rc.local` (a default boot script for MongoDB that I can't seem to find any documentation on). Feeling brave, I deleted that file, rebooted the server, and got the same error as above.

Frustrated, I shutdown the server and went to bed. The next morning, I woke up, booted the server, and everything worked as expected. The mongod process was running; the directory `/var/run/mongodb` existed; everything was fine.

However, when I rebooted the server I again got the error message.

What is happening here?? Is `rc.local` not being run on reboot? If so, how can I get it to do so? Is there a better way of achieving my goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the preferred way to handle startup services in Ubuntu is by using [upstart configuration files](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#job-configuration-file), which are located in `/etc/init`.

Looking at `/etc/init/mongodb`, I found a section that looked like this:

```
pre-start script
    mkdir -p /var/lib/mongodb/
    mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb/
end script
```

To which I added:

```
mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/run/mongodb
```

And that seemed to do the trick!